# Criação de tabelas Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, sqldeveloper

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
create table socio
(
    id_socio integer Not NULL,
    nome varchar(256)  not NULL,
    cpf  varchar(11) not NULL,
    email varchar(256),
    id_situacao integer,
    constraint socio_id_socio_PK primary key(id_socio),
    constraint socio_id_situacao_FK foreign key(id_situacao) references situacao(id_situacao)
);

CREATE TABLE "SITUACAO" (
    Id_Situacao INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Situacao VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT SITUACAO_ID_SITUACAO_PK PRIMARY KEY(Id_Situacao)
);

CREATE TABLE MARCA (
    Id_marca INTEGER not NULL,
    Marca VARCHAR(128) not NULL,
    CONSTRAINT MARCA_ID_MARCA_PK PRIMARY KEY(Id_marca)
);

create table CARRO -- Aqui é a  linha 24
(
    id_CARRO integer Not NULL,
    Modelo VARCHAR(128) not NULL,
    Cor VARCHAR(64) not NULL,
    placa VARCHAR(10) not NULL,
    constraint socio_id_socio_PK primary key(id_CARRO),
    constraint marca_id_marca_FK foreign key(Id_marca) references MARCA(Id_marca),
    constraint socio_id_socio_FK foreign key(id_socio) references socio(id_socio)
);
```

Comment: Qual o erro que está dando?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deve criar as tabelas que são usadas como referencias nas chaves estrangeiras primeiro. Sugiro a seguinte ordem:

```
CREATE TABLE situacao (
  Id_Situacao INTEGER NOT NULL,
  Situacao VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT SITUACAO_ID_SITUACAO_PK PRIMARY KEY(Id_Situacao)
);

CREATE TABLE MARCA (
  Id_marca INTEGER not NULL,
  Marca VARCHAR(128) not NULL,
  CONSTRAINT MARCA_ID_MARCA_PK PRIMARY KEY(Id_marca)
);

create table socio (
  id_socio integer Not NULL,
  nome varchar(256) not NULL,
  cpf varchar(11) not NULL,
  email varchar(256),
  id_situacao integer,
  constraint socio_id_socio_PK primary key(id_socio),
  constraint socio_id_situacao_FK foreign key(id_situacao) references situacao(id_situacao)
);

create table CARRO (
  id_CARRO integer Not NULL,
  id_marca integer NOT NULL,
  id_socio integer NOT NULL,
  Modelo VARCHAR(128) not NULL,
  Cor VARCHAR(64) not NULL,
  placa VARCHAR(10) not NULL,
  constraint socio_id_socio_PK primary key(id_CARRO),
  constraint socio_id_situacao_FK foreign key(id_marca) references situacao(id_marca),
  constraint socio_id_situacao_FK foreign key(id_socio) references situacao(id_socio)
);
```

Na tabela `carro` você também não criou as colunas que fazem referência às outras tabelas.

Comment: sORACK  eSTA DANDO ISSO AQUI OLHA;

Erro a partir da linha : 13 no comando -
create table socio (
  id_socio integer Not NULL,
  nome varchar(256) not NULL,
  cpf varchar(11) not NULL,
  email varchar(256),
  id_situacao integer,
  constraint socio_id_socio_PK primary key(id_socio),
  constraint socio_id_situacao_FK foreign key(id_situacao) references situacao(id_situacao)
)
Relatório de erros -
ORA-00942: a tabela ou view não existe
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: @NamelessMan tente usar o script que acabei de postar como resposta. Haviam colunas faltando

Comment: Erro a partir da linha : 23 no comando -
create table CARRO (
  id_CARRO integer Not NULL,
  Modelo VARCHAR(128) not NULL,
  Cor VARCHAR(64) not NULL,
  placa VARCHAR(10) not NULL,
  constraint socio_id_socio_PK primary key(id_CARRO),
  constraint socio_id_situacao_FK foreign key(id_marca) references situacao(id_marca),
  constraint socio_id_situacao_FK foreign key(id_socio) references situacao(id_socio)
)
Relatório de erros -
ORA-00904: "ID_MARCA": identificador inválido
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: @NamelessMan sim, eu corrigi isso com a ultima edição. Teste com o código atual

Comment: Erro a partir da linha : 23 no comando -
create table CARRO (......